# Why does this JavaScript function return '2'?

Tags: javascript

I encountered this odd JavaScript function:

```
(function f(){
    function f(){ return 1; }
    return f();
    function f(){ return 2; }
})();
```

For some reason, it returns 2. I thought it would crash the browsers (i.e., recursion)

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Explain why anyone would write obfuscated, hard to understand code like this?  Beats me....

Comment: not sure if this is a duplicate. Of course they are both hoisting related, but come on, really? The questions are different. Might as well close all the hoisting questions...

Comment: @duffymo Sadly, this was actually an interview question that I got wrong.. I agree with you though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Function declarations are hoisted, so it ends up looking like this:

```
(function f() {
    function f() { return 1; }
    function f() { return 2; }
    return f();
})();
```

Which is like this:

```
(function f() {
    var f = function f() { return 1; };
    var f = function f() { return 2; };
    return f();
})();
```

which is equivalent to:

```
(function f() {
    var f = function f() { return 1; };
    f = function f() { return 2; };
    return f();
})();
```

which is equivalent to:

```
(function f() {
    var f = function f() { return 2; };
    return f();
})();
```

and the `f` in the tighter scope is preferred over the outside one.

Comment: WOW! That was an amazingly fast answer!! Thanks minitech. I'll have to wrap my head around it. thanks again.

Comment: *"and the f in the tighter scope is preferred over the outside one."* There actually isn't an outside `f`. The name of the function expression is only available inside the function but is overwritten with the new function definition inside of it.